# How to launch a pdf file in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8

I have the full URL of a pdf file and I was wondering if there is any control (a native pdf browser) for windows 8 which allows one to launch the file. All the examples I've seen here on stackoverflow were of launching a file through isolatedStorage.

But then I've seen this:

```
var task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.Uri = new Uri("something.pdf");
task.Show();
```

So can this be linked to the webBrowser control inside my page, so the user doesn't leave the app ??

Comment: You could go with the `WebBroswer` Task.
var task = new WebBrowserTask();
task.Uri = new Uri("url of the pdf");
task.Show();

Answer (score 1):

If you have a internet URL for the PDF, you can use the `WebBrowserTask` or `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` to hand it over to the system to open it in an app (or offer the user to search the store for one if none is installed).

There is no built-in way to view PDF in Windows Phone, however, there are 3rd party components that can do this, like in [Component One Studio](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerPhone/)

Answer (score 0):

you can download and install an PDF reader app from the store on your wp8 device and open your PDF document with it